# Looking for a _one byte_ invalid opcode with x86

Tags: exception, assembly, x86

I need an invalid opcode with x86 (not x64!) that's exactly **one byte** in length to overwrite some code in a foreign process. Currently I'm using INT3 (0xCC) but it would be nicer to trap an invalid opcode separately since the foreign process contains a lot of valid INT3.

Comment: Don't think there is one. 0F1h (int1) may be the closest but it isn't implemented on all levels of machines. Refer to https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insINT1

Comment: there's none http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

Comment: According to http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#xF1, there aren't any in 32-bit mode.  (@ecm: according to that, on CPUs where it's not treated as `icebp` / `int1`, it's undefined but doesn't raise `#UD`.)

Comment: Not what I hoped but thank you very much to all of you. You're great.

Comment: it's weird to see that you've asked so many questions without [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) any. It's not quite how stackexchange works

Answer (score 5):

According to http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html, there aren't any in 32-bit mode guaranteed to `#UD`.  Anything that wasn't nailed down has been reused as building material for new extensions.

The ones that exist in 64-bit mode are reserved and not guaranteed to fault on future CPUs; only `ud2` is truly guaranteed future-proof.  Assuming x86-64 lasts long enough, likely some vendor will make use of that 64-bit-only coding space and stop wasting code-size to also cater to increasingly obsolete 32-bit mode.

If you don't need `#UD`, you can raise `#GP(0)` with some privileged instructions in user-space, assuming you're never going to be running in kernel mode.

**[`F4  hlt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt) will always `#GP(0)` in user-space**, not enabled by IOPL, only true CPL=0.  (Or #UD if used with a lock prefix).  Even if it somehow gets executed in a kernel context, it just stops and waits for the next interrupt, so typically no effect on correctness unless executed with interrupts disabled.  (In which case you're stuck until the next NMI).

A similar but worse option is `FB  sti`.  But it can execute successfully in a program that's used Linux `iopl()`, like an X11 server.  Unless interrupts were supposed to be disabled, though, that's still not going to lock up your system, it just won't trigger the exception you were looking for.  (Unlike `cli` which could get that CPU stuck, or `in al, dx` which could do wild IO and even be allowed by `ioperm` not just `iopl`, depending on what value is in DX.)

---

**Depending what comes next in memory, `9A  callf ptr16:32`** might fault on trying to load an invalid value into CS.  That value would come from the 2 bytes of machine code 5 and 6 bytes after this one (i.e. after a 32-bit new EIP, since `ptr16:32` is stored little-endian).  Unlike `call rel32` or whatever, it may fault *before* actually pushing anything and overwriting the current CS:EIP.  (But if not, in theory your debugger could simulate popping that far-return address back into CS:EIP after catching the fault.)

Just to be clear, I'm suggesting overwriting a byte with `9A`, and leaving the later bytes of machine code unmodified, *after checking that the bytes that would be the new CS value are in fact invalid*.  e.g. by making sure a far call to that address segfaults.  Or if this is near the end of a page, and the next is unmapped, it can `#PF`.

---

**[The `F0  lock` prefix faults with `#UD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lock)** if used on things other than a memory-destination RMW operation, so it can also work if later context would decode as any other instruction.  But you can't always use it; you need to check that you aren't creating a valid atomic RMW instruction.  e.g. if the ModRM byte was `00` or `01`, replacing the opcode with a `lock` prefix creates a memory-destination `add`.

@ecm points out that `f1` on some CPUs is `icebp` / `int1`, but on other CPUs where it isn't, it's undefined but doesn't raise `#UD`.  (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#xF1)

If the following byte is `0`, `D4 00   aam 0` is guaranteed to `#DE` (divide exception).  But any other value does immediate 8-bit division of AL.

---

Depending what byte comes next, `CD  int n` can be used.  But not for all following bytes, e.g. `int 0x80` won't fault under Linux (unless your kernel is built without CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION).  And you might not want some of the other random interrupt numbers.  e.g. `CD 03  int 3`  is pretty much like `CC   int3`.

Comment: I think `CD` can also be used, although it'll be tricky to handle the interrupt

Comment: I already had a satisfactory answer, but such extensive answers are really great. I love this platform.